# PIL (Pillow) saves pngs with "libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL (Pillow 6.0.0) to same some images as PNGs. However, for some of them, I get

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

When trying to read them, again with PIL. It still works, it's just a warning. Then, on some images, I get

> ValueError: Decompressed Data Too Large

---

I understand how that can happen in the wild, however, my images are created from JPGs, which are opened with PIL, resized, cropped, and saved. How can it save something that it cannot read? And can I prevent this?

Comment: PIL is a bit outdated. Can you try Pillow instead?

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually using Pillow

Comment: Can you show simplest possible code to read an *"unhappy"* JPEG and write it which will cause the errors you mention - please provide the JPEG too.